# Randomizing a user dataclass with pytest and hypothesis

Tags: python, pytest, python-hypothesis

I can *manually* define an `Address` builder strategy:

```py
import attrs
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st

@attrs.frozen(kw_only=True)
class Address:

    street: str
    city: str

AddressStrategy = st.builds(
    Address,
    street=st.text(),
    city=st.text()
)

@given(AddressStrategy)
def test_proper_address(address):
    assert len(address.city) < 4
```

When I run pytest, it indeed catches my bug:

```
address = Address(street='', city='0000') # <--- counterexample address found - good !

    @given(AddressStrategy)
    def test_proper_address(address):
>       assert len(address.city) < 4
E       AssertionError: assert 4 < 4
E        +  where 4 = len('0000')
E        +    where '0000' = Address(street='', city='0000').city

main.py:23: AssertionError
```

According to [the docs](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html?highlight=register_type_strategy#hypothesis.strategies.register_type_strategy), it seems like it *should be possible* to use an auto-generated address builder:

> `builds()` will be used automatically for classes with type annotations on **init** ...

But when I try the following options, neither work:

- `st.register_type_strategy(Address)`
- `@given(Address)`

Comment: So what's your problem? `AddressStrategy = st.builds(Address, street=st.text(), city=st.text())` works as desired.

Comment: @WillZhao the strategy is boilerplate code - it seems like it should be generated automatically

Comment: using decorator `@given(st.from_type(Address))` works for me. Also, the first one should be used in this way: `st.register_type_strategy(Address, SomeStrategy)` with `@given(SomeStrategy)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# If you don't specify city and street, st.builds() will infer them from types
address_strategy = st.builds(Address)

# Or you can use various stronger grades of magic:

@given(st.from_type(Address))  # <-- get me an instance of this type
def test_proper_address(address): pass

@given(address=...)            # <-- infer the address strategy from type hints
def test_proper_address(address: Address): pass

@given(...)                    # <-- infer *all* strategies from type hints
def test_proper_address(name: str, address: Address): pass
```

The goal is that you can use as much magic as you like, but can *also* wind it back gradually if you need to customize just a little bit more of each strategy.  For example, maybe we need at-most-length-four strings for the city?

```
address_strategy = st.builds(
    Address,
    # street=st.text(),       # <-- no need to spell this out, it'll be inferred
    city=st.text(max_size=4)  # <-- but we do want to customize this one
)

# After we register this strategy, the more-magic options will infer it correctly:
st.register_type_strategy(Address, address_strategy)  # <-- e.g. in `conftest.py`

@given(...)
def test_proper_address(address: Address):
    assert len(address.city) < 4  # <-- this will pass now!
```

Comment: wow that's cool ! so if I understand correctly, the `st.register_type_strategy` is needed to *refine* inputs and specialize them further than their types right?

Comment: It completely overrides whatever would have been inferred!  In practice you should probably be generating a subset of possible values for the type, but if I'd written `city=st.integers()` you'd get Addresses where the city was an integer.